# MySQL update query with where condition only updating one record

Tags: php, mysql, sql-update, where-clause, min

I have two tables:

1. Product details - For storing product information.
2. Product Listings - For multiple copies that may be sold by different users.

I'm using this select query to gather the lowest price of products with the same name on the `listings table = (SELECT product_name, MIN(price) FROM product_listings GROUP BY product_name)`. **$product** & **$min_price** are the variables I'm using for the two fields respectively.

This works fine and gives me the lowest price of all products with the same product_name.

```
product_name | Lowest price
Title        | £0.69
Title        | £7.98
```

Now I want to update the product details table (specifically the "lowest_price" column) with this data so that each dynamically rendered product shows the price of the cheapest copy available.

So far I have managed to update only one record with this `update query = ("UPDATE product_details SET lowest_price='$min_price' WHERE product_name='$product'");`

Is it possible to update all records with an update query like this? Why is it only updating one record?

Comment: what is the relation between product_details and product_listings? (ie, the related fields. is it just product_name ?)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming you have a product_id in your product_listings table, which relates to an id field in your product_details table, you can do this:

```
update products p 
    inner join (
        select product_id, min(price) min_price 
            from product_listing 
            group by product_id
        ) pl 
    on p.id = pl.product_id 
    SET p.min_price = pl.min_price
```

If that's not the case, and you only have the product name to join on (not such a good idea), it'd be this:

```
update products p 
    inner join (
        select product_name, min(price) min_price 
            from product_listing 
            group by product_name
        ) pl 
    on p.product_name = pl.product_name 
    SET p.min_price = pl.min_price
```

Example fiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/9b928/1

Comment: Yes the relation is product_name. There is a product id field on the product listings table for each individual copy that will be inserted. The product details table will only be used to store universal information about the product i.e. product image, description. I'm having trouble implementing the code, getting a few syntax errors, unexpected t-strings. I've been coding with the old style MySQL does it make a difference? Thanks for the quick reply.

Comment: post your code and your errors and we'll see whats up

Comment: Ahh I'm dumb! Apologies, the code works fine I didn't realise that you left out the s on product_listings. All working great now thank you so much your a star!!! :D